# Search for a value in another list, if found delete entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search for a value in another list, and if found I need to delete the entire row - the following is giving me an error: `object variable or with block variable not set`

```
' 1. For each transcation number in email opt in list:
' 2.   Search for transaction number in Salesforce list
' 3.   Delete entire row

Sub emailList()
Dim optIn As Range, optOut As Range, cell As Range, found As Range

Set optIn = Worksheets(1).Columns("B")
Set optOut = Worksheets(2).Columns("A")

For Each cell In optIn
    Set found = optOut.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    
     found.EntireRow.Delete
Next cell
End Sub
```

If anyone could advise what I may be missing, would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

_Here are the things I changed:
_1. define optin and optout ranges in terms of cells, not columns. Troubleshooting with "cell.select" revealed that the for loop was checking the whole column, not a single cell _

_2. Add "If Not found Is Nothing Then" to make sure the code doesn't try to delete a row that doesn't exist because cell was not found.  _

```
Sub emailList()
Dim optIn As Range, optOut As Range, cell As Range, found As Range
Set optIn = Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2), Worksheets(1).Cells(10, 2))
Set optOut = Range(Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 1), Worksheets(2).Cells(10, 1))

For Each cell In optIn

Set found = optOut.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
         
If Not found Is Nothing Then
Worksheets(2).Cells(found.Row, 3).EntireRow.Delete
End If

Next cell

End Sub
```